# Empty variable after function is complete

Tags: angularjs

I have a `addMovie` function in this template,

```
%ul#showresults
  %li.search_results{"ng-if" => "movie.release_date && movie.poster_path", "ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList | orderBy:'-release_date'"}
    .addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie(movie)"}
      %span
        Add Movie
```

When a user clicks the `.addmovie` div the `addMovie(movie)` function fires,

```
$scope.wishlistID = [];

$scope.addMovie = function(movie) {
  $scope.wishlistID.push({id: movie.id});
  var movieID = $scope.wishlistID[0].id;
  console.log (movieID)

  movieAdd.add(movieID)
   .then(function(response){
      $scope.movieListID = response;
```

This function pushes the ID of the movie record that's been added into a scope called `wishlistID` and passes it into a variable. Then it requests a function called `add` in the `movieAdd` service and passes the `movieID` variable with it,

```
var service = {};
var baseUrl = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';

function httpPromise (url) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    method:'JSONP',
    url: url
  })
    .success(function(data){
      deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(){
      deferred.reject();
    });
  return deferred.promise;
}

service.add = function(movieID){
  return httpPromise(
    baseUrl + movieID + '?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=' + '&append_to_response=releases&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
}
```

The service does a JSONP request and returns the data which get put into the `movieListID` scope.

Now if I add a movie it stores the ID of that movie into the variable, something like `140048`, but if I enter a new searchquery and add a different movie the variable `movieID` still has the `140048` value, which causes the app to add the same movie again (even though there's been a new search action, and a new movie!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you keep grabbing the same index of the wishListID array, which is the first index (the first movie you add).

```
var movieID = $scope.wishlistID[0].id;
```

Why not update this line to match:

`movieAdd.add(movie.id)`

Instead of:

`movieAdd.add(movieID)`

Edit:

Are you just trying to find the key value that the movie was added for? Instead of the 'movie id' that the object contains, that is passed through the function.

Comment: or use unshift instead of push

Comment: Thanks Sean, that indeed fixed it, and looks better.

Comment: @koox00 unshift adds a new item to the front of the array? That could work, but I just need one result. So using the id as an argument looks fine.